# How do I separate classes for MVC design pattern in Java (KeyListener separate from JFrame)?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, keylistener

I am making an arkanoid game in java using the MVC design pattern and I do not know how to make the Controller class seperate from the view Class. Its should be simple enough task i want to make the keyListener in the controller class while keeping all the visual stuff in the View class (i can deal with the model myself). For some reason I cannot find how to do that. For now i have one view class that extends JFrame and implements keylistener.

I would prefer an answer that posts 2 small classes with the code.

Answer (score 0):

In Swing the `View` and `Controller` are mostly the same classes, e.g. [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) (View & Controller) + [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) (Model).
If you want a clean separation you could take a look at [JGoodies](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jgoodies&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jgoodies.com%2F&ei=B2EWUNqwIonR4QTb4YCYDw&usg=AFQjCNEwECNCdkUN_ZYGrOYsfkLGIogO8w) which is a data binding framework for Swing but I'm not sure if it will be the best solution for a game.
Of course you could implement your own `Logic Layer`, e.g.

```
public interface GameStateListener {
  public void playerPositionChanged(Player p, Position oldPos, Position newPos);
}

// Stores the current state of the game
public class DefaultGameState implements IGameState {
  public void addGameStateListener(GameStateListener) {...}
}

// Contains the logic of the game
public class DefaultGameLogic implements IGameLogic {
  public DefaultGameLogic(IGameState gameState) {...}
  public void doSomething(...) { /* update game state */ }
  ...
}

// displays information of the game state and translates Swing's UI
// events into method calls of the game logic
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements GameStateListener {
  private JButton btnDoSomething;

  public MyFrame(IGameLogic gameLogic, IGameState gameState) {
    // Add ourself to the listener list to get notified about changes in
    // the game state
    gameState.addGameStateListener(this);

    // Add interaction handler that converts Swing's UI event
    // into method invocation of the game logic - which itself
    // updates the game state
    btnDoSomething.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed() {
        gameLogic.doSomething();
      }
    });
  }

  // gets invoked when the game state has changed 
  // (might be by game logic or networking code - if there is a multiplayer ;) )
  public void playerPositionChanged(Player p, Position oldPos, Position newPos) {
    // update UI
  }
}
```

Using Java's [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) interface is not really convenient since you need to find out what properties of the observed object have changed.
Therefore using a custom callback interface is a common way to implement this.